# Access cryptographic secure random generator

Tags: pgfmath, random-numbers

I am writing my Master's Thesis in cryptography at the moment. The main part deals with randomness; therefore, I wanted to make a little Tikz picture in the introduction to show an example of randomness. Of course, I could create a random string somewhere else and just import it to LaTeX, but this approach feels unsatisfying. My question: Is there a way to access a cryptographic secure random number generator directly from LaTeX, e.g. within a Tikz picture? I assume my solution using `random()` from pgf math is not cryptographic secure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \row in {0,1,...,7}{
                \foreach \column in {0,1,...,7}{
                    \pgfmathparse{random(0,1)}
                    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                        \draw[fill, black] (\row, \column) rectangle (\row +1, \column + 1);
                    \fi
                }
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Edit:
To be more accurate on the secure part: I am searching for a random generator, that is accepted as a standard, e.g. by Nist. For those more interested in the topic, here is a [reference](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/random-bit-generation).

Comment: I think for the benefit of the general readership you could define 'cryptographically secure' here. I think it's likely that neither the `pgf` macro-based implementation nor the engine primitives are going to meet the requirement.

Comment: Are you familiar with LuaLaTeX and the ways you could access Lua's `math.random` function?

Comment: @Mico I suspect that's the same, though: is it going to meet the criteria required by someone working on cryptography?

Comment: I think the best way to explain secure is using an example: In Java there is the easy solution using ```random()``` and the secure version ```SecureRandom()``` and I am searching for ```SecureRandom()``` for LaTeX

Comment: @JosephWright - I agree with you. :-) Lua's [reference guide](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.random) states that the `math.random` function "uses the xoshiro256** algorithm to produce pseudo-random 64-bit integers, which are the results of calls with argument 0. Other results (ranges and floats) are unbiased extracted from these integers." Hopefully, the OP will know whether this explanation indicates that the resulting pseudo random numbers are 'cryptographically secure'.

Comment: As far as I know, xoshiro256** is a good and fast allrounder, but not cryptographic secure. In general, Nist chooses the standard algorithms and some crypto library implements them and then one can use these libraries. I have no idea weather something like that is even possible for LaTeX

Comment: The generator in `pgf` uses a linear congruency generator, as is documented in `pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex`.

Comment: @Titanlord As I said, I think you need to adjust the question to make it clear what would be acceptable here. Remember that random functions in (La)TeX are aimed at e.g. providing 'interest' in figures, choosing questions from a pool, etc., not cryptography.

Comment: You can find a secure random generator in Lua [here](https://pastebin.com/D1th4Htw). It's an implementation of ISAAC CSPRNG in Lua. So you should be able to use it with LuaLaTeX. However the randomness depends on the used entropy. There are several more implementations of secure random generators in Lua available via internet. So I would suggest to use LuaLaTeX and try one (or more) of them.

Comment: You could create a one time pad (so to speak) and read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-shell-escape` to make a call to some program on your platform that implements a CSPRNG.

In the following example, I use `/dev/urandom` via `od` using a suggestion from [Heitor's log](https://heitorpb.github.io/bla/2020/04/07/bash-random-numbers/), because `/dev/urandom` on macOS uses [*Fortuna*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\settorandomnumber}{m}
 {% #1 = macro to be set
  \sys_get_shell:nnN
   { od ~ -vAn ~ -N4 ~ -t ~ u4 ~ < ~ /dev/urandom } % execute
   { \endlinechar=-1 } % ignore endline
   \l_tmpa_tl % store in
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl / (2^32) } } % normalize
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\settorandomnumber\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandomnumber\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandomnumber\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandomnumber\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

The call to `od` generates a random integer between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup> − 1 (inclusive), and we can divide to get a number in the interval [0,1).

[image]

Here's also a “random bit generator”: we can generate just a one-byte number and check whether it's larger than 127.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\settorandomnumber}{m}
 {% #1 = macro to be set
  \sys_get_shell:nnN
   { od ~ -vAn ~ -N4 ~ -t ~ u4 ~ < ~ /dev/urandom } % execute
   { \endlinechar=-1 } % ignore endline
   \l_tmpa_tl % store in
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl / (2^32) } } % normalize
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\settorandombit}{m}
 {% #1 = macro to be set
  \sys_get_shell:nnN
   { od ~ -vAn ~ -N1 ~ -t ~ u4 ~ < ~ /dev/urandom } % execute
   { \endlinechar=-1 } % ignore endline
   \l_tmpa_tl % store in
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_tmpa_tl } > {127} { 1 } { 0 } }

 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\settorandomnumber\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandomnumber\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandomnumber\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandomnumber\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandombit\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandombit\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandombit\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\settorandombit\pgfmathresult \pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OP wants either `0` or `1` on a random basis.

Comment: @AlexG I was able to archive getting 0 and 1 by adding the round function inside the floating-point evaluation: ```\fp_eval:n { round( \l_tmpa_tl / (2^32) ) }``` - I hope this does not conflict with my initial goal

Comment: @Titanlord You can use just one byte instead of four and round.

Comment: @Titanlord : 0.5 always rounds up to 1. So you may get slightly more ones than zeros.

Comment: I did that using ```{ od ~ -vAn ~ -N1 ~ -t ~ u1 ~ < ~ /dev/urandom }``` // Is exactly 0.5 a possible fp-value? Otherwise this should not be a problem

Comment: @Titanlord I added the random bit generation